# Eclipse and GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github

I trying to move my droid project from my local PC to a private GitHub repo.  My problem is that when I right-click my project and got Team -> Share Project, I only see a CVS screen.

I tried to manually add EGit but Eclipse (Indigo) complains that it is already there.

Any ideas how I can force Eclipse to choose Git not CVS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with Git in Eclipse... it's not very good.

Using the Git plugin for eclipse is great so you can easily see you dirty files without asking for them, so you can see your current branch at all times, for fixing conflicts, and for looking at past commits with the ref log history.

But for actually using Git commands I personally prefer the control of the terminal.

That being said, it sounds like you are going to the correct place (right click->team->share->Git).  You could also try to create a git repo for the project through terminal and then import it into eclipse (You can import a git repo under File->import).  Once your repo is imported you can right click it and load the project into Eclipse (cool feature).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm on Windows 7.  When I go to File -> Import, I see Gneral, CVS, Install, Run/Debug, Tasks, Team and XML.  Where is the Git option?

Comment: @user1174838 Platform will not matter.  Git can be installed on windows to be used in cmd. Eclipse is a java application and runs the same on all OS's. It sounds to me like you do not have EGit. I would re-download Eclipse - http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2

Comment: Re-installed Eclipse and the installed eGit from the Eclipse Market.  I can choose git now.

Comment: @user1174838 Good deal... sometime Eclipse can be a pain.  You can also try to delete the .meta data folder associated with it - I have had this fix problems before, however you will lose the application settings you have set when u do this.